# What are the accessibility considerations for confirmation buttons in modal dialogs?

Tags: user-interface, modal-dialog, accessibility, wcag2.0

Consider a modal dialog where a user can select an item from a list.

Option 1: Instantly close the modal upon selecting an item from the list.

Option 2: Have a selected state for the selected item and provide OK / Cancel buttons to confirm the selection before closing the modal.

Which of the two options is preferred from an accessibility standpoint? (considering keyboard navigation support, etc). Note that the selection is non-destructive and the user could easily re-open the modal and change the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 is your best option [here is some guidance related to this](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html) and the [WCAG guideline](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change)

Basically do not change context, update lists etc. automatically on any type of input, you should always give the user a chance to confirm their actions.

Now the question is do you really need a modal if all the user is doing is selecting an item from a list?

Surely it would be a better UX to just have a list you can choose from (this depends on what you are doing, just thought I would point it out as you didn't give an example).

You also need to consider the fact that your modal list should present number of options, currently selected options etc. etc. Yet again these are just guesses and something to consider, it could be irrelevant.

Comment: I think it really depends, and probably needs more context to decide. As an example, let's say if I click a rate button to open list of options. I'm not sure if I want to get a confirmation asking do I really want to rate 3 stars? Especially if it's something you can review/change/undo, I think conformation just ads another keystroke for user to dismiss. Usually screen reader users want UI to be clear and concise, not verbose. I don't think confirmation dialog isn't really an accessibility concern.

Comment: I think the key here is if you open a modal just to rate 3 stars then your UX is already broken (you added the unnecessary step already asking me to open a modal in the first place). If information is complex enough to need a modal, then it is complex enough to require confirmation that the information is correct. I am not saying there aren't edge cases but odds are if you don't want a confirm on a modal, you shouldn't have used the modal in the first place (which is why I asked whether this could just be a `<select>`) Try a modal with a screen reader, it is confusing if it auto dismisses.

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I just wanted to point out that especially if users can review/change/undo whatever they did in modal after they dismiss modal, confirmation is probably not necessary. I think this is more UX decision in general, not necessarily accessibility.

Comment: No I understand, but the point I was trying to make (badly) was if something is complex enough to be taken out of document flow, you probably want a confirmation. This is true for everybody not just people with disabilities, if I scroll through a massive list of items in a modal and click the wrong one I don't want to have to wait for the modal to reopen (because it will likely have a 500ms fade-in and be positioned away from where my mouse was at the time) I just want to click something else. You are right there are exceptions but I prefer to give general good guidance and let people decide.

Comment: Agree with @GrahamTheDev re Option 2 here, but I'm adding another thought for anybody finding this years later like I just have. When setting up a confirmation dialog where there are two buttons (e.g. OK / Cancel) consider how you style these two, since focus styles when toggling between two options can easily make it ambiguous as to which button currently has focus. Adding an outline to the element with focus can help, as can styling the cancel very simply (almost like a simple link) compared to the affirmative button (with a border, etc).